# I've switched back from HTTPS to HTTP now the page doesn't load in Chrome

Tags: http, https, google-chrome

I've switched my website `www.intelli.bet` back from https to http and now I can't get on it using Chrome (my default browser).

I was previously hosting with `Firebase` which is a great platform, but I don't really need their data storage and my web design skills are poor so I am now using a Go Daddy hosted WordPress site. Firebase provided free `HTTPS` certificates, whereas Go Daddy don't. I don't really see that as being an issue for my website at this time and would rather save money as I try to grow it.

However, when I type the address into the bar of Chrome it always redirects to the (now defunct) HTTPS address and gives an error message: `This site can’t provide a secure connection`.

Using the browser on my phone works fine, my wife's phone works fine and Firefox is able to load the page on my machine.

I have tried clearing the DNS cache in chrome but that's had no effect. I'm worried that people using my site will run into the same issue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You probably either had permanent redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, or you had [HTTP strict transport security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (HSTS) enabled which are still in your cache.

As far as I know clearing your cache should work to delete a redirect, to clear the HSTS settings in Chrome: `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`  and *"Delete"* your domain.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Are all of my users who already use Chrome and accessed the HTTPS site going to have to do that same thing? That could be a problem. Would paying for an SSL certificate and returning to HTTPS help, or would that cause issues?

Comment: Yes, other returning visitors probably experience the same. As Tero already explained, re-establishing HTTPS would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your site most probably issues HSTS headers to visitors, which tell the browser that the site should always be loaded with `https`. The browsers remember these header settings for each site, and refuse to load it without `https`.

So, every visitor who visited your site when it had been set up with `https`, has received these HSTS settings. Every one of those visitors cannot visit your site until the `max-age` setting of HSTS is reached.

You can view your domain HSTS status with instructions from this post: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68883/checking-domains-hsts-status

Now, you have two options:

1. Wait until the `max-age` of HSTS expires. However, `max-age` is usually really long, so that is not a realistic option.
2. Get a new certificate for the site, and this will fix the issue. You might also be able to use the previous private key / certificate, if you still have access to them and they are still valid.